# Meteor template listener not working

Tags: javascript, meteor

Template:

```
<template name="contactModal">
    <div class="remodal contact-modal" data-remodal-id="contactModal">
        <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>
        <h2>It's good to talk.</h2>
        <div class="form-container">
            <form>
                <div class="element-container">
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name"/>
                </div>
                <div class="element-container">
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your E-Mail Address"/>
                </div>
                <div class="element-container">
                    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="element-container">
                    <a data-action='send-email'>Send</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
Template.contactModal.events({
    'click *': (event) => {
        console.log('clicked');
    }
});
```

Aaaand ... I never get the console.logged text. I have other listeners working just fine, so I'm thoroughly bemused by this. The only difference is that the contactModal template is a modal handled by remodal, and thus invisible on page load.

Comment: I'm not familiar with remodal but is it possible that it has set `pointer-events: none` via css or elsewhere?

Comment: Definitely possible. I'll !important that to its usual value and report back.

Comment: One way I could think of is use (body events)[https://github.com/gwendall/meteor-body-events] and see if it works from there. Eg: ```Template.body.events({ 'click .remodal'(event){ .... } });```

Comment: Nope, pointer-events isn't being altered anywhere. I'd rather not use body-events if I can avoid it, since I can't escape the feeling that this *should* be perfectly possible without any kind of hacky workaround.

I've checked that the js file is being processed, and it is, but is there a way to verify which event listeners are present (and, ideally, what code should run when they're fired)?

Answer (score 0):

For event handlers attached to elements in modals and other elements that are not visible on page load you would need to attach the event listener when the modal is shown, something like the below sample using a bootstrap modal event:

```
    Template.modalTemplate.events({
        'shown.bs.modal #modal-to-open-id':(event, template) => {
           $('.some-element').on('click', (e) => console.log('clicked');
        }
    });
```